# When writing software do all programs have a signature?

Tags: antivirus, software

I have always been curious if all software have a signature for whatever reason or is only related to AV.

Comment: There's a different and mostly unrelated concept called digital/cryptographic signature/hash, you can compute the digital/cryptographic signature of any files, including program files, for example Microsoft Authenticode and PGP signature on Linux packages. AV signature is something totally different though and can be basically anything that the AV vendor decided to use to detect a particular malware, such as file hash, byte patterns in the file, behavioral patterns, the use of detection avoidance technique, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Signature* in an AV context can be anything that uniquely identifies software. It might be a string from within the program, or even a hash of the program itself. Something doesn't have an AV signature until a person says "this is malicious, we need to find a way to unambiguously detect it".

Comment: What about in a development context?

Comment: @Joe No, I don't think so. Signature is an ambiguous word anyway.

Comment: Okay thank you for the quick replies and for clearing up my confusion

Comment: I will in two minutes when i am allowed

Comment: AV signature is not necessarily unique. In many cases, a class of malware may have been detected by the same signature (e.g. they all make a certain syscall, write to a certain file/registry, or make a connection to a certain server). That's why it's not uncommon that a harmless program got caught in the net.

Comment: @LieRyan I was under the impression that those false positives are typically the fault of heuristic-based detection, not signature-based detection.